# Is there faster way to randomly swap one "0" to one "1" in a one dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, scipy

I would like to randomly swap one `0` and  one `1` in a one dimensional array which contain only 0 and 1 many many times say up to `N = 10^6`. Here is my code for doing the swap one time.

```
import numpy as np

# a contains only 0 and 1
a = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1])
# j1 random position of 0, j2 random position of 1
j1 = np.random.choice(np.where(a==0)[0])
j2 = np.random.choice(np.where(a==1)[0])
# swap
a[j1], a[j2] = a[j2], a[j1]
```

Since I would like to do this process many many time, at every iteration, I need to use np.where() to locate posistions of 0 and 1, which I think is not that efficient.

**Is there any other approach which can be more effecient ?**

Comment: @LMD, I tried that one also, it seems not too much improved. But I do need a careful testing later.

Comment: @Eumel, thank you for pointing this specific case:) It do help in some sense.

Comment: @LMD, it speed up indeed, my original code had some other heavy stuff within the loop, that's why I said not improved too much. thanks anyway:)

Comment: Yesterday I warned about using `a[j1], a[j2] = a[j2], a[j1]` to swap array values.  For a 1d array this isn't a problem.  But if the array is 2d, so that `a[j1]` is `view` (an array) this will be a problem   `a[[j1,j2]] = a[[j2,j1]]` is safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could maintain the result of the `where` expressions yourself, as swaps are executed, so that you don't need to re-execute that `where` call. You'd only do it once, at the start of the procedure, but then in the loop, you'd incrementally adjust.

Also, the swap can be replaced by two assignments, since you know that the 0 will become 1 and vice versa.

```
a = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1])

# One-time preprocessing

zeroes = np.where(a==0)[0]
ones = np.where(a==1)[0]
num_zeroes = len(zeroes)
num_ones = len(ones)

# In a loop:

for _ in range(100):
    # Choose random indices in zeroes/ones
    j0 = np.random.randint(num_zeroes)
    j1 = np.random.randint(num_ones)
    # Get the chosen indices for use in `a`:
    i0 = zeroes[j0]
    i1 = ones[j1]
    # Keep the two collections in sync with the swap that now happens
    zeroes[j0] = i1
    ones[j1] = i0
    # The swap itself
    a[i0] = 1
    a[i1] = 0

    # ...
```

Note that the length of `zeroes` and `ones` doesn't change: we can just reuse the two slots that were selected at every swap.

Comment: saving the results from the where expressions before entering the loop makes the execution inside the loop twice as fast (measured with ~11000 array elemets): 0.0001295 seconds vs. 0.0002377 seconds previously

Comment: `i0 = zeroes[j0]` will break if you get an index thats higher than the length of zeroes

Comment: You might group your data by groups of 32, then use a butwise xor to swap a full group. Your code would be reduced to a[:]=a[:]^randrange(x100000000)

Comment: @Eumel, indeed, should be `randint` instead of `choice`. Updated.

Comment: Note that `np.where` was previously slow in this use-case but it has now been significantly optimized in the very last version of Numpy (1.23). See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/21130. Thus, the random indexing are now more likely to be the issue in the last version.

Answer (score 1):

I want to drop what i described in my comment here as an answer based on the assumption that the array is somewhat close to a 50:50 distribution of 0s and 1s.

The beauty of this approach, while not on a fixed execution time the time complexity in regards to the array size is O(1) so for larger arrays it can handily beat trincots approach.

```
length = 1e8
a = (np.random.randint(0,2,int(length))).astype(np.uint8)

t = time.time_ns()
rng = np.random.default_rng()
for i in range(10000):
    b = rng.integers(0, length)
    while(True):
        c = rng.integers(0, length)
        if c == b:
            continue
        if a[c] != a[b]:
            a[c] ^= 1
            break
a[b] ^= 1
print((time.time_ns()-t)/1e9)

# Trincot

t = time.time_ns()
zeroes = np.where(a==0)[0]
ones = np.where(a==1)[0]
num_zeroes = len(zeroes)
num_ones = len(ones)

for _ in range(10000):
    # Choose random indices in zeroes/ones
    j0 = np.random.randint(num_zeroes)
    j1 = np.random.randint(num_ones)
    # Get the chosen indices:
    i0 = zeroes[j0]
    i1 = ones[j1]
    # Keep the two collections in sync with the swap that now happens
    zeroes[j0] = i1
    ones[j1] = i0
    # The swap itself
    a[i0] = 1
    a[i1] = 0
print((time.time_ns()-t)/1e9)
```

result:

```
0.1360712
1.3667251
```

Comment: 50:50 case is special but very important too!!!

Comment: @ted930511 the approach works regardless of distribution, but the time taken starts to scale up at ~10:90

Comment: I don't know about NumPy's, but in Python's, using random() like that has a slight bias and the random() call itself is faster than the randint() call, so that doesn't seem fair. Also, what if b==c? Then you flip the same value twice and didn't actually change anything. And `^= 1` seems simpler (does that not work in numpy)?

Comment: @KellyBundy numpys random is supposedly unbiased and i only use randint to create an example test-set so optimization here is irrelevant. b==c is unlikely but a fair point and i didnt know about ^= 1, that makes it much simpler, thank you

Comment: Yes, random() alone is unbiased but *using random() like that* isn't. The multiplication with the length and conversion to int creates a bias (unless the length is a power of 2).

Comment: If you wait with the b-flip until after you found c, you don't need the extra c==b check

Comment: @KellyBundy Out of curiosity, do you know how big the bias is that way? And both things fixed, thank you

Comment: Hmm, now the b-flip is outside the loop. I guess the bias is as small as it can be. Let's say random() could produce 1024 values. And length is 100. Then the 100 indexes can't all have the same chance with your old way. Optimal is if some have chance 11/1024 and the rest have chance 10/1024.